# Update UI while Task.Run or TaskFactory.StartNew is still working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, task-parallel-library

So I have decided to rewrite my Mail client in WPF as I think it's about time I move on from Windows Forms (I still like it), but I am facing a bit of a problem.

I use a `BackgroundWorker` in my Windows Forms app to do stuff and in a foreach I `worker.ReportProgress(currentProgress);` and this allows me to update the UI as things are being done in the background which is great.

But just now after starting a new WPF project, I notice that there is no `BackgroundWorker` in the Toolbox (for WPF apps) so I go searching online, and found that some people have problems updating the UI while using `BackgroundWorker` with WPF. So this makes me think that using `BackgroundWorker` in a WPF app is a bit hacky - and I don't want that.

On that same page, another user refers them to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page, telling them to use `Task.Run` instead of `BackgroundWorker` in WPF. Upon looking at `Task.Run` docs, I immediately see how it can be useful, however I do have one concern. I do not see a way to "Report Progress" or to update the UI as things are being done. All I see is how to Run a Task and "`await`" it; leaving me with just one option - update the UI after the long-running Task has completed.

How can we update the UI of a WPF desktop app while `Task.Run`/`TaskFactory.StartNew` is still working?

Comment: The `BackgroundWorker` class is one of the main ways of updating the UI on a background thread in WPF. What articles have you seen that suggest it's hacky?

Comment: Thank you @AndrewStephens - the reason I assumed it was hacky was because 1) it's not in the Toolbox for WPF apps by default, 2) You have to manually add worker.SupportsProgress = true; (due to lack of Properties Pane for this control, 3) I can see that other people have said that BackgroundWOrker cannot update UI from inside the WorkerCompleted or ProgressChanged events without using delegates (which aren't necessary in WinForms) - that lead me to believe that maybe BGWorker isn't fully supported or not meant to be used in WPF apps.

Comment: It's a class not a UI control, so it won't be in the toolbox. You'll typically create an instance of it within your code-behind, or your view-model if using MVVM. The ProgressChanged event is raised on the UI thread, so no delegate needed. I'm sure WorkerCompleted does too, but if not just wrap the UI update code within a `Dispatcher.Invoke()` call. Again you'll find this is a common technique in WPF, especially when updating the UI from other threads.

Answer (score 6):

You can stick with `BackroundWorker` if you so choose. There is nothing really hacky about it although it is very old-school. As others said, if you can't find it in your toolbox, you can always declare and initialise it straight from your code (don't forget the `using System.ComponentModel;` directive).

Stephen Cleary has an excellent series of blog posts on `BackgroundWorker` vs `Task`, which highlights the differences and limitations of each approach. It's definitely worth a read if you're on the fence or just curious.

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html

If you do decide to go down the `Task` + `async/await` route, there are a couple of things specifically related to progress reporting that you should keep in mind.

Generally you should be aiming to have your `await Task.Run` encapsulate the smallest meaningful amount of work possible. The rest of your `async` method will then execute on the dispatcher `SynchronizationContext` (assuming that it was started on the dispatcher thread) and will be able to update the UI directly, like so:

```
List<object> items = GetItemsToProcess();
int doneSoFar = 0;

foreach (var item in items)
{
    await Task.Run(() => SomeCpuIntensiveWorkAsync(item));

    doneSoFar++;

    int progressPercentage = (int)((double)doneSoFar / items.Count * 100);

    // Update the UI.
    this.ProgressBar.Value = progressPercentage;
}
```

This is the easiest way of implementing progress reporting in the `async` world.

The only time I can imagine reporting the progress from within the body of the delegate you pass to `Task.Run` is when you're processing a *very* large number of items, and the processing of each item takes a very short time (we're talking 10,000 items per second as a rough guide). In such a scenario creating a large number of extremely fine-grained `Task`s and `await`ing them will introduce significant overhead. If this is your case you can fall back to the progress reporting mechanism introduced in .NET 4: `Progress<T>`/`IProgress<T>`. It's quite similar to the way the `BackgroundWorker` reports progress (in that it relies on events) and it provides a bit more flexibility in terms of deciding when you get to post back to the dispatcher context.

```
public async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    // Let's assume we're on the UI thread now.
    // Dummy up some items to process.
    List<object> items = GetItemsToProcess();

    // Wire up progress reporting.
    // Creating a new instance of Progress
    // will capture the SynchronizationContext
    // any any calls to IProgress.Report
    // will be posted to that context.
    Progress<int> progress = new Progress<int>();

    progress.ProgressChanged += (sender, progressPercentage) =>
    {
        // This callback will run on the thread which
        // created the Progress<int> instance.
        // You can update your UI here.
        this.ProgressBar.Value = progressPercentage;
    };

    await Task.Run(() => this.LongRunningCpuBoundOperation(items, progress));
}

private void LongRunningCpuBoundOperation(List<object> items, IProgress<int> progress)
{
    int doneSoFar = 0;
    int lastReportedProgress = -1;

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        // Process item.
        Thread.Sleep(1);

        // Calculate and report progress.
        doneSoFar++;

        var progressPercentage = (int)((double)doneSoFar / items.Count * 100);

        // Only post back to the dispatcher SynchronizationContext
        // if the progress percentage actually changed.
        if (progressPercentage != lastReportedProgress)
        {
            // Note that progress is IProgress<int>,
            // not Progress<int>. This is important
            // because Progress<int> implements
            // IProgress<int>.Report explicitly.
            progress.Report(progressPercentage);

            lastReportedProgress = progressPercentage;
        }
    }
}
```